# WGET - Exclude .ZIP files, while downloading the website

Tags: linux, web, download, wget

I'm downloading a complete website using wget. I would like to know that how can I modify this terminal command so that it excludes / skips / doesn't downlaod any .zip file.

```
wget -m -k -K -E -p --convert-links -e robots=off http://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--reject` parameter

```
wget --reject *.zip ...
```

[GNU Wget Manual (**2.11 Recursive Accept/Reject Options**)](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options)

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -m -k -K -E -p --convert-links -e robots=off -R zip http://www.example.com/
```

Took this from GNU's manpage of Wget:

```
‘-R rejlist --reject rejlist’
    Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject (see Types of Files). Note that if any of the wildcard characters, ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’ or ‘]’, appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: shouldn't the first command be like: `wget -m -k -K -E -p --convert-links -e robots=off -R *.zip http://www.example.com/`

Comment: As far as I undestand the man page, giving zip,html,gif would reject all files that have the suffix zip,html,gif. Worked when I tried it a few minutes ago with a small webpage.